Evaluating an embedded JSONata string in Amazon State Language
How can I ensure that a nested JSONata expression resolves in AWS Step Functions?
I have the following input to a state:
{ "value1": "something", "value2": "{% $states.input.value1 %}" }

The value2 field is intended to dynamically reference value1. However, it does not resolve as expected. I attempted to work around this by creating a new object in the state output and passing the JSON string:
{
    "mapped": "{% $states.input %}"
}

However, the nested JSONata expression in value2 remained unresolved.

Expected behavior: The expression {% $states.input.value1 %} should resolve dynamically to the value of value1. The resolved output would look like this:
{ "value1": "something", "value2": "something" }


Actual behavior: The expression remains as a string and does not resolve dynamically. The output looks like this instead:
{ "value1": "something", "value2": "{% $states.input.value1 %}" }



Is there a way to force such expressions to resolve in this context? The input can vary, but the reference will always point to a valid path. Any guidance on how to approach this would be appreciated!

Currently, state inputs are not evaluated for JSONata expressions.
I suggest adding a Pass state as the first step in your workflow. In that state, you can use Assign to assign values from $states.input to variables.
For a detailed explanation of variable assignment, see Evaluation order in an assign field in the documentation.
